# How do I make a menu that declares a variable within Javascript

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick

Here is my menu:

```
<a id="page1" href="" onclick="var = page1">Home</a>
 <a id="page2" href="" >About us</a>
 <a id="page3" href="" >Services</a>
 <a id="page4" href="" >Partners</a>
 <a id="page5" href="" >Contact us</a>
```

All i need is an onclick that declares a variable in javascript, since I'm not very skilled in javascript i need some help please.

Comment: This will fail because JavaScript doesn't know what `page1` is, and you didn't state a variable name. You need `onclick="var page = 'page1';"` You can also use `onclick="var page = this.id;"`

Comment: Where is the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

This is invalid syntax:

```
var = page1
```

You have to give the variable a *name*:

```
var someVariable = page1
```

And, of course, `page1` must be defined somewhere, otherwise this will produce an error.  Or perhaps you meant this?:

```
var page1 = 'some value'
```

---

Note however that this *probably* isn't what you're trying to do.  Sure, you can "declare a variable" in a click event, but what does that actually accomplish?  What other code is *using* that variable?  Why not declare the variable in the scope where you want it and then just *update its value* in the click event?  (Which should really be encapsulated within an aptly-named function.  Ideally a click event should simply invoke a function, the event itself shouldn't have lines of code in it.)

We can *probably* provide more meaningful help if you can elaborate on what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jQuery, it's quite simple, just invoke a function that creates the variable (keep in mind that you will only be able to operate with that variable inside that function), or if you need it anywhere else, create the variable at global scope and just use the function to modify it.
For exmample:
HTML:

```
<a id="page1" onclick="makevar('hello word')">Home</a>
<a id="page2" href="" >About us</a>
<a id="page3" href="" >Services</a>
<a id="page4" href="" >Partners</a>
<a id="page5" href="" >Contact us</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var var1="";
function makevar(varcontent){
var1=varcontent;
alert(var1);
}
```

See both options working here https://jsfiddle.net/3Lyeo6kc/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/3Lyeo6kc/2/

Comment: Ok thank you, that has helped. Though I've repeated the onclick across to the rest of the menu's, they all work apart from the last one? I can't see any mistakes that I could have made.